# Meteor.js: Linking Twitter and Facebook to a Password based account

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, meteor, oauth

I'm currently trying to set up my application in such a way that users can connect their Twitter, and/or Facebook accounts to their password based account within my application.

I've built a custom account system on top of [accounts-ui-unstyled](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui-unstyled), and I have both [accounts-twitter](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-twitter), accounts-facebook, and [meteor-link-accounts](https://github.com/yubozhao/meteor-link-accounts) installed, and I've tried many different things, but none of them seem to work.

All I need to have happen is on button click, let a user sign in with twitter, and once signed in, update the current user with that account being linked. Ideally once that happens, you'd be able to reclick that same button to undo the link.

Does anyone have experience doing this? Should I use different packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working through this problem today.  Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mackbrowne/30317eba75d13683566ead357b52bbce)

Add this to your server code, you'll get the functionality you want.  Also for security make email verification on all accounts mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is actually built in functionality of the meteor accounts API. (http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) But it sounds, from your description, that you are already using that.

Working with Twitter and Facebook for login, you do have to register your application with Twitter and Facebook for the oauth to work. Did you do that? What are your specific errors?

Comment: The main problem I'm having is that I'm getting 0 feedback. If I click one of the buttons, a window will popup for 1-2 seconds, show twitter or FB and redirect back to my app and close the window. All while I'm getting no errors, and no updated services actually on the user.

Comment: hmmm I have seen that before. Can you run it with something like chrome dev tools and watch the network traffic and see what is coming over the line? Maybe it's getting a strange redirect or an error is being suppressed?